# React-Native: Download Image from Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

**Pre-Informations:**

I still have a Firebase project opened and I am successfully still using the Firebase Database (*So the* `firebase.initializeApp(config)` *works*). 
I uploaded several Images at my Firebase Storage in the folder "*/Images/*" and named them *image1.jpg*, *image2.jpg*,..

React-Native: 0.31.0, 
Firebase: 3.3.0

**What I want:**

I want to get the Image from the Firebase Storage and put them into an `<Image>`

**What I actually did:**

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('Images/image1.jpg');

//1. Try:
storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log(url);
)}

//2. Try:
var sampleImage = storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log(url);
)}

//3. Try:
var sampleImage = storageRef.getDownloadURL();
```

**Informations about the code:**

1. The code doesn't reach the `console.log(url)` point

   2.1. Tried to use the `sampleImage` as `source` in a `<Image>` object: **empty Image**

   2.2. Tried to `log` the `sampleImage`: **`undefined`**

   2.3. Tried to `log`the `url`: **didnt reach this point**

   3.1. Tried to use the `sampleImage` as `source` in a `<Image>` object: **empty Image**

   3.2. Tried to `log` the `sampleImage`: **`{ F: 0, ka: undefined, o: { F: 0, ... } }`**

All tries returned the same error code after 2-3 minutes.

> Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try
>   again.

Thank you very much in advance for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

I reported this issue to Firebase support and I got the following response:

> Our engineers got back and it seems that this is an Android-specific issue (works on iOS) [..] We are currently working on this, but as to the timeline, we could not share anything as of the moment

**Research**

It appears that this is an actual bug caused by react-native's XMLHttpRequest acting up. When trying the getDownloadURL() in the same way you describe the same thing happens (ie. Max Retry time reached).

However when overriding react-native's polyfill of XMLHttpRequest as described in [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38063958/3050999) getDownloadURL() will finish normally and return a valid URL.

We are using react-native v0.33.0, Firebase v3.4.1

**Workaround**

We have been using this workaround in the meantime; bypassing the Firebase API:

```
var bucket = firebase.storage().ref().bucket;
var firebaseUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" + bucket + "/o/";
var finalUrl = firebaseUrl + 'path%2Fto%2Fresource';
firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken()
.then((token) => {
  fetch(finalUrl, {headers: {'Authorization' : 'Firebase ' + token}})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    var downloadURL = finalUrl + "?alt=media&token=" + responseJson.downloadTokens})
  })
});
```

This is an issue that seems to affect a small amount of users since I have only seen the problem raised otherwise [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/5-tips-for-firebase-storage.html#c8958839988751601927). However this appears to be an actual bug and it is very debilitating when it occurs, so any more input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. At the moment i have no time to test this solution and I found a workaround (Taking the direct URL of the picture), but i will try as fast as I can. Thank you in advance. BR Jonathan

Comment: Didn't work for me: "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined".

Comment: I got it. I was testing using node.js only (not react native). The function fetch is being loaded with react native's dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Your first one seems right based on the docs. I believe you're getting an error so wire up an error callback as well:

```
storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    console.log(url);
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL

Answer (score 1):

**TO get All the Images From the storage**

```
firebase.storage().ref().child('filename').list().then(result => {
    // Loop over each item
    result.items.forEach(pics => {
        firebase.storage().ref().child(pics.fullPath).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            console.log(url);
            //these url will be used to display images
         })
     });
})
```