# How can I see an actual error from server (react native)?

Tags: react-native

I send a request:
[image]

And get an error:
[image]

How can I see details of this error?

Comment: You've got a `.catch` on the `post` Promise. That means your `try ... catch` block won't catch anything. Do a `JSON.stringify` on `res` inside that `.catch` and see what else you get. Right now `toString` is called on it, which might hide an actual response body / error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `debugger` to look at all of your Network requests.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997443/how-can-i-view-network-requests-for-debugging-in-react-native) question will allow you to view your requests.

(Assuming you're on iOS) - Once you've added the code and your application is running, click on `Hardware > Shake Gesture` and then select `Debug JS Remotely`.

Once the debugger opens, you should start to see your requests on the `Network` tab.