# React - sending the correct data to server and get error

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create a login in `react-native`. For that I send the user info to the webservice. if the info is correct the server will return a `json`

The problem is that I send the correct user info to the server and I get an error message as if I put the incorrect info

But when I test with `Postman` with the same info I dont get any error message

constructor

```
constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            showPass: true,
            press: false,
            username: "",
            password: ""
        }
    }
```

function that fetch the data

```
checkLogin = () => {
        const { username, password } = this.state;
        var url = 'https://xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/auth/login'

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username, password
            })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if (!responseJson.errors) {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('foto');
                console.log(username + " 1");
                console.log(password + " 1");
            } else {
                Alert.alert('Error', responseJson.message, [{
                    text: 'Fechar'
                }]);
                console.log(username + " 2");
                console.log(password + " 2");

            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
```

Inputs

```
<TextInput onChangeText={text => this.setState({ username: text })} />
<TextInput onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })} />

<TouchableOpacity style={Style.btnLogin} onPress={() => this.checkLogin()} >
        <Text style={Style.textoLogin}>Entrar</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

JSON that I get from `Postman` with the same info from the input

```
{
    "errors": false,
    "type": "-",
    "line": "-",
    "message": "Login successfully!",
    "user": {
        "user_id": 2,
        "name": "xxxxxxx",
        "username": "xxxxxxxx",
        "email": "xxxxx@xxxxx.pt"
    },
    "_token": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: in your code are you setting `value={this.state.<variable>}` on the TextInput ?

Comment: yes I'm setting

Comment: I suspect your request body is not being formatted in the way you think it is. Have you tried checking your browser dev tools network tab and inspecting the request and body to make sure it's formatted as your API expects? EDIT: I now see this is `react-native`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997443/how-can-i-view-network-requests-for-debugging-in-react-native can help you get the Chrome debugger setup to view network requests.

Comment: @LMulvey where should I use that?

Comment: Could get a little complex. Before you go that route, do you have access to this server's code? Are you able to debug there and log out what you're actually receiving from these requests?

Comment: I've tried but the app dont run if I have the CORS enable. And no, I dont have access to the server code

Comment: Did you check pass username,password same to you are type in textFileds? body: JSON.stringify({
                username, password
            })

Comment: Could you maybe try it without stringifying. I think fetch also supports objects as its body.

Comment: @Rik are you telling me just to try `body: JSON({
                username, password
            })`  ?

Comment: No, Just without json

Comment: @Rik cant to I get `unsupported bodyinit type` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem, I had to change my `body` to a `FormData()`

Here is the code:

```
checkLogin = () => {

        var url = 'https://xxxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/auth/login';
        const { username, password } = this.state;
        /*const username1 = this.state.username;
        const password1 = this.state.password;
        var data = {
            "username" : this.state.username,
            "password" : this.state.password 
        }*/
        var formData=new FormData();
        formData.append('username', username);
        formData.append('password',password);


        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
           // body: JSON.stringify(data)
           body: formData
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            if (!responseJson.errors) {
                this.storeData(JSON.stringify(responseJson.user), responseJson._token)
                this.props.navigation.navigate('foto');

            } else {
                Alert.alert('Error', responseJson.message, [{
                    text: 'Fechar'
                }]);


            }


        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
```