# Fail to connect to GraphQL API server

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I'm running an online GraphQL API, it seems to work fine when I'm trying postman for example to make requests, but always fails, with Apollo Link React-native, that returns error: TypeError: Network request failed.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const token = this.props.account.accessToken || "";
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: config.graphql_host,
  credentials: "same-origin",
});
const websocket = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://${config.ws_host}`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  },
});
const middleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext({ headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
  return forward(operation);
});
const splitlink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  websocket,
  httpLink
);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  connectToDevTools: true,
  link: concat(middleware, splitlink),
  cache: cache,
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network", errorPolicy: "all" },
    query: { fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network", errorPolicy: "all" },
  },
  mutate: { errorPolicy: "all" },
});
```

package.json:

```
  "@apollo/client": "^3.1.3",
  "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",
  "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
  "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
```

I get the error as follow:

```
Error: Network error: Network request failed
    at new ApolloError (bundle.umd.js:92)
    at Object.error (bundle.umd.js:1330)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:140)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:179)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (Observable.js:240)
    at bundle.umd.js:1107
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.error (bundle.umd.js:1106)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:140)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:179)
```

Comment: what link you are hitting??

Comment: debug raw network response, probably contains additional, more descriptive error message

Comment: I'm searching how, but can't find.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55450655/6124657

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the SSL installed on the server was invalid so I had to use Free Let's Encrypt SSL and worked perfectly. In fact the request was reject constantly.