# best way to debug React-Native application?

Tags: debugging, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to React-Native Development.

Previously, I developed many applications in different Hybrid mobile application frameworks (Ionic, Cordova, etc.)
Debugging is very easy on Ionic, Cordova frameworks applications.

Please suggest the best way to debug React-Native applications

Comment: There's the [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) app, it works fine for redux and you can also dispatch actions from there. It sometimes "blocks" for a few seconds if you are outputting a lot of console.logs/warns/errors. 
The http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ is better if you are console.logging a lot of things, it doesn't block

Comment: You can use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997443/how-can-i-view-network-requests-for-debugging-in-react-native/55450655#55450655) if you not already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my past experience, the best and easy way to debug React Native Applications is by using [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) Application(Developed by Facebook for React-Native App)

Answer (score 2):

if you’re using Android Emulator then press **CTRL + M** from your computer keyboard to open the debug menu.

if you’re using iOS Simulator then press **CMD + D** from your computer keyboard to open the debug menu.

Click on **Debug with Chrome** to open the Chrome Debugger Tool in your computer. After opening the Debug tool in your Chrome.

**Right Click on the screen -> Inspect .**

Now you can see the Debugger Console Window on the Right Side of Screen. Select Console TAB.

Now in your app you can putlogs to debug app.

**console.log('debugging');**

Example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { View, StyleSheet, Text, LogBox } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  //LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Remote debugger']);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  }, []);

  console.log('App Called...');

  return (
    <View style={styleSheet.MainContainer}>

      <Text style={styleSheet.text}>
        Debug App in Android Emulator in React Native using Chrome Debugger Tool.
      </Text>

    </View>
  );
}

const styleSheet = StyleSheet.create({

  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 27,
    padding: 10
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use expo for your react-native project you should use the [expo-cli](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/)
otherwise the [react-native-cli](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli) with an emulator or a phone connected in debug mode.