# JSON Parse issue in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm so lost.

I keep getting this error:

> "SAVED SCREEN NETWORK ERROR: , [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']
> at node_modules/color-string/index.js:90:16 in cs.get.rgb" (Line 90 is right below my console.log in the code down below)

This part:

```
console.log(match)

        if (match[4]) {
            if (match[5]) {
                rgb[3] = parseFloat(match[4]) * 0.01;
            } else {
                rgb[3] = parseFloat(match[4]);
            }
        }
    } else if (match = string.match(per)) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            rgb[i] = Math.round(parseFloat(match[i + 1]) * 2.55);
        }
```

But when I check the node_modules, I can't understand at all where its even using JSON. I console logged the match and all I'm getting is this:

Array [
"rgb(28, 28, 30)",
"28",
"28",
"30",
undefined,
undefined,
]

I literally don't know what to do anymore, so I'm hoping someone more experienced can help me out on this.

```
/* MIT license */
var colorNames = require('color-name');
var swizzle = require('simple-swizzle');
var hasOwnProperty = Object.hasOwnProperty;

var reverseNames = {};

// create a list of reverse color names
for (var name in colorNames) {
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(colorNames, name)) {
        reverseNames[colorNames[name]] = name;
    }
}

var cs = module.exports = {
    to: {},
    get: {}
};

cs.get = function (string) {
    var prefix = string.substring(0, 3).toLowerCase();
    var val;
    var model;
    switch (prefix) {
        case 'hsl':
            val = cs.get.hsl(string);
            model = 'hsl';
            break;
        case 'hwb':
            val = cs.get.hwb(string);
            model = 'hwb';
            break;
        default:
            val = cs.get.rgb(string);
            model = 'rgb';
            break;
    }

    if (!val) {
        return null;
    }

    return {model: model, value: val};
};

cs.get.rgb = function (string) {
    if (!string) {
        return null;
    }

    var abbr = /^#([a-f0-9]{3,4})$/i;
    var hex = /^#([a-f0-9]{6})([a-f0-9]{2})?$/i;
    var rgba = /^rgba?\(\s*([+-]?\d+)(?=[\s,])\s*(?:,\s*)?([+-]?\d+)(?=[\s,])\s*(?:,\s*)?([+-]?\d+)\s*(?:[,|\/]\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)(%?)\s*)?\)$/;
    var per = /^rgba?\(\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)\%\s*,?\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)\%\s*,?\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)\%\s*(?:[,|\/]\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)(%?)\s*)?\)$/;
    var keyword = /^(\w+)$/;

    var rgb = [0, 0, 0, 1];
    var match;
    var i;
    var hexAlpha;

    if (match = string.match(hex)) {
        hexAlpha = match[2];
        match = match[1];

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            // https://jsperf.com/slice-vs-substr-vs-substring-methods-long-string/19
            var i2 = i * 2;
            rgb[i] = parseInt(match.slice(i2, i2 + 2), 16);
        }

        if (hexAlpha) {
            rgb[3] = parseInt(hexAlpha, 16) / 255;
        }
    } else if (match = string.match(abbr)) {
        match = match[1];
        hexAlpha = match[3];

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            rgb[i] = parseInt(match[i] + match[i], 16);
        }

        if (hexAlpha) {
            rgb[3] = parseInt(hexAlpha + hexAlpha, 16) / 255;
        }
    } else if (match = string.match(rgba)) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            rgb[i] = parseInt(match[i + 1], 0);
        }

        console.log(match)

        if (match[4]) {
            if (match[5]) {
                rgb[3] = parseFloat(match[4]) * 0.01;
            } else {
                rgb[3] = parseFloat(match[4]);
            }
        }
    } else if (match = string.match(per)) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            rgb[i] = Math.round(parseFloat(match[i + 1]) * 2.55);
        }

        if (match[4]) {
            if (match[5]) {
                rgb[3] = parseFloat(match[4]) * 0.01;
            } else {
                rgb[3] = parseFloat(match[4]);
            }
        }
    } else if (match = string.match(keyword)) {
        if (match[1] === 'transparent') {
            return [0, 0, 0, 0];
        }

        if (!hasOwnProperty.call(colorNames, match[1])) {
            return null;
        }

        rgb = colorNames[match[1]];
        rgb[3] = 1;

        return rgb;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rgb[i] = clamp(rgb[i], 0, 255);
    }
    rgb[3] = clamp(rgb[3], 0, 1);

    return rgb;
};

cs.get.hsl = function (string) {
    if (!string) {
        return null;
    }

    var hsl = /^hsla?\(\s*([+-]?(?:\d{0,3}\.)?\d+)(?:deg)?\s*,?\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)%\s*,?\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)%\s*(?:[,|\/]\s*([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)\s*)?\)$/;
    var match = string.match(hsl);

    if (match) {
        var alpha = parseFloat(match[4]);
        var h = ((parseFloat(match[1]) % 360) + 360) % 360;
        var s = clamp(parseFloat(match[2]), 0, 100);
        var l = clamp(parseFloat(match[3]), 0, 100);
        var a = clamp(isNaN(alpha) ? 1 : alpha, 0, 1);

        return [h, s, l, a];
    }

    return null;
};

cs.get.hwb = function (string) {
    if (!string) {
        return null;
    }

    var hwb = /^hwb\(\s*([+-]?\d{0,3}(?:\.\d+)?)(?:deg)?\s*,\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)%\s*,\s*([+-]?[\d\.]+)%\s*(?:,\s*([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)\s*)?\)$/;
    var match = string.match(hwb);

    if (match) {
        var alpha = parseFloat(match[4]);
        var h = ((parseFloat(match[1]) % 360) + 360) % 360;
        var w = clamp(parseFloat(match[2]), 0, 100);
        var b = clamp(parseFloat(match[3]), 0, 100);
        var a = clamp(isNaN(alpha) ? 1 : alpha, 0, 1);
        return [h, w, b, a];
    }

    return null;
};

cs.to.hex = function () {
    var rgba = swizzle(arguments);

    return (
        '#' +
        hexDouble(rgba[0]) +
        hexDouble(rgba[1]) +
        hexDouble(rgba[2]) +
        (rgba[3] < 1
            ? (hexDouble(Math.round(rgba[3] * 255)))
            : '')
    );
};

cs.to.rgb = function () {
    var rgba = swizzle(arguments);

    return rgba.length < 4 || rgba[3] === 1
        ? 'rgb(' + Math.round(rgba[0]) + ', ' + Math.round(rgba[1]) + ', ' + Math.round(rgba[2]) + ')'
        : 'rgba(' + Math.round(rgba[0]) + ', ' + Math.round(rgba[1]) + ', ' + Math.round(rgba[2]) + ', ' + rgba[3] + ')';
};

cs.to.rgb.percent = function () {
    var rgba = swizzle(arguments);

    var r = Math.round(rgba[0] / 255 * 100);
    var g = Math.round(rgba[1] / 255 * 100);
    var b = Math.round(rgba[2] / 255 * 100);

    return rgba.length < 4 || rgba[3] === 1
        ? 'rgb(' + r + '%, ' + g + '%, ' + b + '%)'
        : 'rgba(' + r + '%, ' + g + '%, ' + b + '%, ' + rgba[3] + ')';
};

cs.to.hsl = function () {
    var hsla = swizzle(arguments);
    return hsla.length < 4 || hsla[3] === 1
        ? 'hsl(' + hsla[0] + ', ' + hsla[1] + '%, ' + hsla[2] + '%)'
        : 'hsla(' + hsla[0] + ', ' + hsla[1] + '%, ' + hsla[2] + '%, ' + hsla[3] + ')';
};

// hwb is a bit different than rgb(a) & hsl(a) since there is no alpha specific syntax
// (hwb have alpha optional & 1 is default value)
cs.to.hwb = function () {
    var hwba = swizzle(arguments);

    var a = '';
    if (hwba.length >= 4 && hwba[3] !== 1) {
        a = ', ' + hwba[3];
    }

    return 'hwb(' + hwba[0] + ', ' + hwba[1] + '%, ' + hwba[2] + '%' + a + ')';
};

cs.to.keyword = function (rgb) {
    return reverseNames[rgb.slice(0, 3)];
};

// helpers
function clamp(num, min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(min, num), max);
}

function hexDouble(num) {
    var str = Math.round(num).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    return (str.length < 2) ? '0' + str : str;
}
```

Comment: Are you parsing JSON elsewhere in your app?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm not using JSON parse anywhere else, my head is about to explode

Comment: Can you see the network requests the app is making? Because this error is typically caused by the server sending back HTML instead of JSON (like a 404 page), so that might help narrow down what's happening (since the stack trace is clearly off for some weird reason)

Comment: @ChrisG unfortunately don't know how to do that with react-native/Xcode, but the fact it's saying JSON "<" like clearly the match doesn't have that anywhere, never had a good experience with React Native to be honest

Comment: Open up your dev tools in your browser. There's a network tab in there. Run your script and you will all the things that are being requested.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997443/how-can-i-view-network-requests-for-debugging-in-react-native